# NodeJS + amazon-sp-api >> How to get the products list

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

I'm using the code see below to get all details about my product on Amazon :

```
let activeProductsResponse = await APIs[ idProductsStocksPlace ].callAPI({
                  operation: 'getListingsItem',
                  endpoint: 'listingsItems',
                  query: {
                    marketplaceIds: el.credentials.MarketplaceIds,
                    includedData:  ['attributes']
                  },
                  path:{
                    sellerId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
                  }
                });
```

Unhopefully I don't succeed to find the way to collect the list of all products available on my shop. I did some tests like the with endpoint «productSearch.searchItems», but it's a generic research not only on my products...

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help me.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to get the listing by the endpoint listingsItems. You have to use the report functions, create, ..., download
Or the downloadReport function :

```
await APIs[ idProductsStocksPlace ].downloadReport({
  body:{
    reportType:'GET_FLAT_FILE_OPEN_LISTINGS_DATA',
    marketplaceIds:[el.credentials.MarketplaceIds]
  },
  version:'2021-06-30',
  interval:8000
});
```